# If else/switch Combination

Tags: javascript

I don't know if,else/switch all that well and i don't know if you can combine them, i'm not sure if that's the case or i just did the brakets wrong, but i spent hours to find the issue and i can't find it.Here's the whole code just in case:

```
const Fanta = 250,Sprite = 250,Cola = 250,Dirol = 450,Snickers = 300,Lays = 800;
var a = prompt("1:Fanta = 250, 2:Sprite = 250, 3:Coca Cola = 250, 4:Dirol = 450, 5:Snickers = 300, 6:Lays = 800");
function math()
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
alert("You chose Fanta");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money)
if(money >= 250)
{
    alert("You just purchased a Fanta! Take back " + (money - Fanta));
}
default:
{
alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
}
}
    switch(a)
    {
        case 2:
alert("You chose Sprite");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money)
if(money >= 250)
{
    alert("You just purchased a Sprite! Take back " + (money - Sprite));
}
else
{
alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
}
}
    switch(a)
    {
        case 3:
alert("You chose Cola");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money)
if(money >= 250)
{
    alert("You just purchased a Coca Cola! Take back " + (money - Cola));
}
else
{
alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
}
}
    switch(a)
    {
        case 4:
alert("You chose Dirol");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money)
if(money >= 450)
{
    alert("You just purchased a Dirol! Take back " + (money - Dirol));
}
else
{
alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
}
}
    switch(a)
    {
        case 5:
alert("You chose Snickers");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money);
if(money >= 300)
{
    alert("You just purchased a Snickers! Take back " + (money - Snickers));
}
else
{
alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
}
}
    switch(a)
    {
        case 6:
alert("You chose Lays");
var money = prompt("Put money in");
alert("You put in " + money)
if(money >= 800)
{
    alert("You just purchased a Sprite! Take back " + (money - Lays));
}
else
{
alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
}
}
}
math();
```

Comment: Use only one switch statement, then list all the cases, closing with the default case.

Comment: From what I remember reading years ago, switch statements use what is known as a "vector jump" in the assembly code. It uses 1 command. However a list of if/else-if/else-if/else-if/else statements, uses more CPU commands. So switches are faster than stacks of if/else statements. Although, with modern CPUs clocking in at 3-4 GHz * 4+ cores, it's a moot point today. Switches can be easier to read, but the code should be properly indented to figure out if there are any missing braces or if they don't properly line up. BTW: These are braces {}. These are brackets: [].

Comment: I tried every answer, none worked, the closest one is @fucedebads, but when i typed in 1, it said you didn't put in enough money, when i was trying to chose a drink

Comment: Richard, it would help a lot if you'd format your code correctly (indents) and state HOW the code is not working (what result you're getting and what result you expect). If you post a question, then notice it needs further work, there's an [edit] link below it you can use.

Answer (score 1):

you should optimize your code better... The default only works in the switch and is in your code the option that no drink. The Answer is you can do that like this:
 ist selected...

```
var enough_money=false; var diff=0; var drink="";
switch(a){
   case(1):
      alert(...);
      if(...){
         enough_money=true;
         diff= money-cola;
         drink= "Cola";
      }
      break;
  case(2):
      alert(...);
      if(...){
         enough_money=true;
         diff= money-cola;
         drink= "Cola";
      }
      break;
  default:
     alert("Please choose!");
}

if(enough_money){
   alert(drink+ ' rest money'+diff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write something like

```
switch(a) {
// switch block
}
switch(a) {
// another switch block
}
// and so on
```

In my humble opinion you need to merge all you switch block in one. And don't forget to put `break` in your `case:` blocks 
So your code will looks like that:

```
switch(a) {
    case x: 
        // case block 1
        break;

    case y: 
        // case block 2
        break;
// other cases
    default:
        // if no one case is matched
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a number of cases, you don't need to write **switch(a)** multiple times. The only thing you need to do is write all cases within single switch() and add **break;** in the end of that case.

The proper way of writing your code would be:

```
const Fanta = 250,Sprite = 250,Cola = 250,Dirol = 450,Snickers = 300,Lays = 800;
var a = prompt("1:Fanta = 250, 2:Sprite = 250, 3:Coca Cola = 250, 4:Dirol = 450, 5:Snickers = 300, 6:Lays = 800");
function math()
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            alert("You chose Fanta");
            var money = prompt("Put money in");
            alert("You put in " + money)
            if(money >= 250)
            {
                alert("You just purchased a Fanta! Take back " + (money - Fanta));
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            alert("You chose Sprite");
            var money = prompt("Put money in");
            alert("You put in " + money)
            if(money >= 250)
            {
                alert("You just purchased a Sprite! Take back " + (money - Sprite));
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            alert("You chose Cola");
            var money = prompt("Put money in");
            alert("You put in " + money)
            if(money >= 250)
            {
                alert("You just purchased a Coca Cola! Take back " + (money - Cola));
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            alert("You chose Dirol");
            var money = prompt("Put money in");
            alert("You put in " + money)
            if(money >= 450)
            {
                alert("You just purchased a Dirol! Take back " + (money - Dirol));
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
            }
        break;
        case 5:
            alert("You chose Snickers");
            var money = prompt("Put money in");
            alert("You put in " + money);
            if(money >= 300)
            {
                alert("You just purchased a Snickers! Take back " + (money - Snickers));
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            alert("You chose Lays");
            var money = prompt("Put money in");
            alert("You put in " + money)
            if(money >= 800)
            {
                alert("You just purchased a Sprite! Take back " + (money - Lays));
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Error! You didn't put in enough money")
            }
            break;
    }
}
math();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(expression) {
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}
```